# Cannot resize the part of the object while the viewpoint is fixed at the zero point of the axis

Tags: modeling

I'm using blender to modeling an object, but I can't resize the part of the object while the viewpoint is fixed at the zero point of the axis，how to solve this problem?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to switch the pivot point (point that acts as center of rotation and scaling) from "3D cursor" to "Median point".

[image]